# Why C++ has introduced separate std::latch and std::barrier?

Tags: c++, synchronization, barrier, countdownlatch, phaser

There are some [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51065637/12357035) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48985967/12357035) on SO. But they only ask the question one way.

[`std::latch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/latch) has an advantage over `std::barrier` that unlike latter, former *can be decremented by a participating thread more than once*.

[`std::barrier`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/barrier) has an advantage over `std::latch` that unlike latter, former *can be reused once the arriving threads are unblocked at a phase's synchronization point*.

But my question is, why have two almost identical things in the first place? Why they decided not combine both of them into one, something like Java [`Phaser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html)?

`Phaser` was introduced in Java7, as a more flexible option over `CountDownLatch` and `CyclicBarrier`, which were introduced in Java5. It has almost identical API as that of both former classes. (Here I took Java's example just to show that combining them is indeed possible.)

Instead of providing a single phaser class, they decided to separately provide latch and barrier, then there must be some benefit from having them separately, mostly some *performance* related issue. So, what is that issue precisely?

Answer (score 3):

C++ has an principle of not paying for something that you don't use. If `std::barrier` can be implemented more efficient than `std::latch` for the case when you don't use it twice from the same thread - there is a reason to provide a more efficient idiom together with a more generic.

As for "what is that issue precisely": C++ has no virtual machine that equalizes all systems. Moreover, STL doesn't specify the exact implementation of the class. So the implementation of latch/barrier is the matter of a system, vendor or taste of the developer.

Comment: > _for the case when you don't use it twice from the same thread_ How is it effiecient? Can you explain.

Comment: Another example may explain you this better: compare `std::lock_guard` and `std::unique_lock`. The latter provides you a richer API, and allows more complex use patterns. So why the standard has both? Because relaxing the requirements on `std::lock_guard` the standard allows the implementers to do it more efficiently. As the result, for the simplest cases the `std::lock_guard` is a recommended widget, and `std::unique_lock` should be used only if you need something that `std::lock_guard` doesn't offer. But technically you can use `std::unique_lock` where `std::lock_guard` is recommended.

Comment: yes, I'm not arguing against what you said. I wanted to know one example implementation where `std::barrier` can be implemented more efficiently than `std::latch`, as the former is not used from same thread twice.